# How to change VAR?

Tags: php, var

I've got a part of a PHP script, but it gives a T_CLASS error.

But i'm not sure how to convert the VAR element into a php5 compliant code...
Can somebody help me?

```
<?php // Defining the "calc" class
if (!class_exists('calc'))
class calc {
var $number1;
}
?>
```

p.s. this is just part of a bigger code, but it keeps saying: "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in your code on line 3". So the error should be either in "class calc {" or in "var $number1;". Please help :P

I had to place the entire code. Just adding the brackets gave me a new error.

```
<?php // Defining the "calc" class
if (class_exists('calc')) {
class calc {
var $number1;
}
}
function boek($number1)
{
$result =$number1 * 2;
echo "Om een tekst van $number1 pagina's te redigeren, rekenen wij: <strong>€ $result,-*</strong></br>";
echo "<small>*Deze prijs is slechts een indicatie. Om een vrijblijvende offerte aan te vragen kunt u gebruikmaken van het contactformulier onderaan de pagina. <br/><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Let op: studenten krijgen op vertoon van hun studentenpas 25% korting.</span></small>";
}
}
//Creating object of class
$calc = new calc();
?>
<style type="text/css">
.calcbutton {
Cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -5000px;
    width: 136px;
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('http://www.mijncreaties.com/wp-content/themes/GoedVerwoord/images/buttons.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.calcbutton {background-position: top left;}
.calcbutton:hover {background-position: center left;}
.calcbutton:active {background-position: bottom left;}
</style>
<form name="calc" action="" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Aantal pagina's: </td>
        <td><input type="text" style="padding-left: 3px;" class="calc-form wpcf7-text" name="value1" value="0" onfocus="if (this.value == '0') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '0';}"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="oper" value="boek">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Bereken prijs" name="submit" class="calcbutton">
</form>
<?

if($_POST['submit']){
$number1 = $_POST['value1'];
$oper = $_POST['oper'];
if(!$number1){
echo "<p><font color=\"red\">Vul a.u.b. een getal in.</font></p>";
}
if($oper == "boek"){
$calc->boek($number1);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you are getting down votes. Because

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping it in an extra set of braces:

```
<?php // Defining the "calc" class

if (!class_exists('calc')) {
    class calc {
        var $number1;
    }
}

?>
```

Editted to add:

```
if (class_exists('calc')) {
class calc {
var $number1;

function boek($number1)
{
$result =$number1 * 2;
echo "Om een tekst van $number1 pagina's te redigeren, rekenen wij: <strong>€ $result,-*</strong></br>";
echo "<small>*Deze prijs is slechts een indicatie. Om een vrijblijvende offerte aan te vragen kunt u gebruikmaken van het contactformulier onderaan de pagina. <br/><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Let op: studenten krijgen op vertoon van hun studentenpas 25% korting.</span></small>";
}
}
}
```

Your closing bracket was in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just tried it at [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) online compiler and without brackets it gives the T_CLASS. I'm sorry. +1

Comment: I geuss I made a mistake. This is just part of a bigger code. And I assumed this was the only problem... I assumed wrong.

When I place the brackets, I get an error somewhere else...

Comment: Did it :D. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @VinnieVanRooij - editted my answer. You need to move your brackets around. Also, you've got `if (class_exists('calc'))` - shouldn't that be `if (! class_exists('calc'))`?

Comment: Yes, it should've been with the ! in it. Now trying out your code.

Comment: You just made me very happy :D. Bit of a novice with php, so I was trying all kinds of things, but never thought of missplaced brackets...

It works now. So thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap brackets around that `if`:

```
<?php    
// Defining the "calc" class
if (!class_exists('calc')){
    class calc {    
        var $number1;    
    }
}    
?>
```

You will have the same issue when conditionally creating functions:

```
<?php    
if (!function_exists('new_function')){
    function new_function{    
       return 'awesome';   
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The other guy was just a little bit quicker with the answer...